# Trace the calls to pull_task() for running processes

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling, strace

I am trying to count the number of times pull_task() is called by processes in my system. pull_task() is a scheduling function that moves a task from runqueue of a busy CPU to the runqueue of an idle CPU.
I could not find any simple mechanism (inclunding perf top) to find this out.

There is a root process called migration in the system, I have a hunch that this process might be responsible for calling pull_task(). But I also cannot attach strace to this process, it throws the following error:

attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): Operation not permitted.

The priority of the process 'migration' is realtime. Perhaps that is the reason why strace cannot attach to it?

Kindly advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at Ftrace. This will give a complete listing of all kernel function calls occurring in your system for some time period.

Turn on the function tracer like so...

```
echo function > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/current_tracer
```

View the trace by 
    cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace

These articles should help:

[Debugging with Ftrace part one](http://lwn.net/Articles/365835/)

[Debugging with Ftrace part two](http://lwn.net/Articles/366796/)